# Why is the recommended QDialog instantiation the way it is?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt Widgets application, created and edited in Qt-Creator.

The main window (MainWindow class) has a menubar, with a button to open a small dialog (with text or widgets for settings).

To create a new "window" I open the "create new file" dialog in Qt-Creator and select Qt Designer Form Class, which creates the needed header, source, and ui files (dialogabout.h, dialogabout.cpp, dialogabout.ui).

If I follow along with the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html), I then open the QDialog like so:

```cpp
QDialog * widget = new QDialog;
Ui::DialogAbout about_ui;
about_ui.setupUi(widget);
widget->exec();
```

This works, but if I modify the new dialog's instantiator to connect a pushbutton to the close signal, the connect statement (along with any other code there) is never reached.

```cpp
DialogAbout::DialogAbout(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::DialogAbout)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    qDebug() << "I'm alive!"; // No output happens
    connect(ui->pushButton_close, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SIGNAL(please_close())); // No signal created on pushbutton click.
}
```

I suspect that this is because I haven't explicitly done `widget = new DialogAbout(this)`. If I instead instantiate the new dialog this different way:

```cpp
DialogAbout * newwindow;
newwindow = new DialogAbout(this);
newwindow->exec();
```

Then the connect statement and qDebug work.

My question is: what are the pitfalls of deviating from the documentation's recommended way to create dialogs? Is there a way to get this functionality with the prior instantiation method?

Comment: please_close() is a SIGNAL or a SLOT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that DialogAbout is not the same as Ui::DialogAbout. Ui::DialogAbout is a class of build placed in the UI namespace, created automatically by uic. In your project, the name of this file should be "ui_dialogabout h".

```
class Ui_DialogAbout
{
public:
    QPushButton *pushButton_close;

    void setupUi(QDialog *DialogAbout)
    {
        ...
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QDialog *DialogAbout)
    {
        ...
    } // retranslateUi

};
namespace Ui {
    class DialogAbout: public Ui_DialogAbout {};
} // namespace Ui
```

Here you use a class QDialog and uses the Ui::DialogAbout to build a layout in it. Note that Ui::DialogAbout has the function to create the components in QDialog.

```
QDialog * widget = new QDialog;
Ui::DialogAbout about_ui;
about_ui.setupUi(widget);
widget->exec();
```

If you specialize QDialog for DialogAbout your code should look like this:

```
DialogAbout * widget = new DialogAbout();
Ui::DialogAbout about_ui;
about_ui.setupUi(widget);
widget->exec();
```

But as setupUi() is already within DialogAbout, you cannot call again, resulting in:

```
DialogAbout * widget = new DialogAbout();
widget->exec();
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I now see how to get the same functionality with either method.